# Neo4j error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I use `StatementResult = session.run(Cypher_query)` to run cypher query with java. The program in concern is used to import nodes from csv files with `LOAD CSV`

This error is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format(Unknown Source)
at java.util.logging.StreamHandler.publish(Unknown Source)
at java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.publish(Unknown Source)
at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Unknown Source)
at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Unknown Source)
at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Unknown Source)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.logging.JULogger.warn(JULogger.java:54)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.security.TLSSocketChannel.close(TLSSocketChannel.java:477)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketClient.stop(SocketClient.java:192)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketConnection.close(SocketConnection.java:260)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.ConcurrencyGuardingConnection.close(ConcurrencyGuardingConnection.java:178)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.PooledSocketConnection.dispose(PooledSocketConnection.java:251)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.PooledConnectionReleaseConsumer.accept(PooledConnectionReleaseConsumer.java:50)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.PooledConnectionReleaseConsumer.accept(PooledConnectionReleaseConsumer.java:29)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.PooledSocketConnection.close(PooledSocketConnection.java:200)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.NetworkSession.closeCurrentConnection(NetworkSession.java:385)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.NetworkSession.syncAndCloseCurrentConnection(NetworkSession.java:359)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.NetworkSession.run(NetworkSession.java:102)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.NetworkSession.run(NetworkSession.java:93)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.NetworkSession.run(NetworkSession.java:73)
```

Is there any way to go around that error? Or is there no way except for importing less nodes?

The whole java code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.AuthTokens;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Driver;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.GraphDatabase;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Record;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Session;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.StatementResult;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class ImporterImprovedVersion {
    private static String path = "file:///C:/csvsToImport/csvs";
    private int num;

    private boolean headerPresent(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
        if(scanner.hasNext()){
            String firstLine = scanner.nextLine();
            scanner.close();

            if(filePath.contains("address")){
                System.out.println("address! " + this.num + " " + firstLine.contains("addr_tag_links"));
                return firstLine.contains("addr_tag_links");
            }else if (filePath.contains("transaction")){
                System.out.println("transaction! "  + this.num + " " + firstLine.contains("value_bitcoin"));
                return firstLine.contains("value_bitcoin");
            }else{
                System.out.println("wallet! "  + this.num + " " + firstLine.contains("primAddress,firstSeenTime"));
                return firstLine.contains("primAddress,firstSeenTime");
            }           
        }
        scanner.close();
        return false;

    }



    public ImporterImprovedVersion(int num, boolean withOutputIndex, Session session, String mainDir) throws FileNotFoundException{
        this.num = num;

        //import csvs and create corresponding nodes
        String folderPath = ImporterImprovedVersion.path + num + "/";
        System.out.println(folderPath);


        String queryAddr = null;
        if(this.headerPresent(mainDir + num + "\\addresses.csv")){
            queryAddr = "LOAD CSV From '" + folderPath + "addresses.csv' AS line"
                    + " WITH line"
                    + " SKIP 1";            
        }else{
            queryAddr = "LOAD CSV From '" + folderPath + "addresses.csv' AS line";      
        }
        String queryWallet = null;
        if(this.headerPresent(mainDir + num + "\\wallet.csv")){
            queryWallet = "LOAD CSV From '" + folderPath + "wallet.csv' AS line"
                    + " WITH line"
                    + " SKIP 1";            
        }else{
            queryWallet = "LOAD CSV From '" + folderPath + "wallet.csv' AS line";
        }

        File tranFile = new File(mainDir + num + "\\transactionRelation.csv");
        String queryTran = null;
        System.out.println(tranFile);
        System.out.println(tranFile.exists());
        if(tranFile.exists()){
            if(this.headerPresent(mainDir + num + "\\transactionRelation.csv")){
                queryTran = "LOAD CSV From '" + folderPath + "transactionRelation.csv' AS line"
                        + " WITH line"
                        + " SKIP 1";                    
            }else{
                queryTran = "LOAD CSV From '" + folderPath +  "transactionRelation.csv' AS line";                   
            }
        }else{
            if(this.headerPresent(mainDir + num + "\\transactionRelation1.csv")){
                queryTran = "LOAD CSV From '" + folderPath +  "transactionRelation1.csv' AS line"
                        + " WITH line"
                        + " SKIP 1";                    
            }else{
                queryTran = "LOAD CSV From '" + folderPath + "transactionRelation1.csv' AS line";                   
            }
        }

        StatementResult sR = session.run(queryWallet 
                + " MERGE (w:Wallet { primWallAddr:line[0]})"
                + " ON CREATE SET w.first_seen = line[1], w.last_seen=line[2]");

        System.out.println("Wallet nodes created");

        sR = session.run(queryAddr + " MERGE (a:Address {AddId:(line[0])})"
                + " SET a.addr_tag_link= CASE WHEN a.addr_tag_link = 'null' or a.addr_tag_link IS NULL THEN line[1] ELSE a.addr_tag_link END,"
                + " a.addr_tag= CASE WHEN a.addr_tag = 'null' or a.addr_tag IS NULL THEN line[2] ELSE a.addr_tag END,"
                + " a.first_seen=line[3], a.last_seen=line[4], a.multiExist= a.multiExist OR apoc.convert.toBoolean(line[6])"
                + " WITH a, line[5] as li5" 
                + " MATCH (a), (wa:Wallet) WHERE li5=wa.primWallAddr"
                + " MERGE (a)-[r:BelongTo{uniqueReferenceBelongTo:(a.AddId + wa.primWallAddr)}]->(wa)"
                + " ON CREATE SET r.primWallAddr = wa.primWallAddr,"
                + " wa.first_seen =  CASE WHEN apoc.date.parse(wa.first_seen, 's',\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss\") < apoc.date.parse(a.first_seen, 's',\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss\") THEN wa.first_seen ELSE a.first_seen END,"
                + " wa.last_seen =  CASE WHEN apoc.date.parse(wa.last_seen, 's',\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss\") > apoc.date.parse(a.last_seen, 's',\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss\") THEN wa.last_seen ELSE a.last_seen END");

        System.out.println("Address nodes created");
        System.out.println("BelongTo rel created");



        if(withOutputIndex){
            sR = session.run(queryTran 
                    + " MATCH (senderAddress:Address {AddId:line[0]}), (senderAddress)-[:BelongTo]->(sender:Wallet),"
                    + " (receiverAddress:Address {AddId:line[1]}), (receiverAddress)-[:BelongTo]->(receiver:Wallet)"
                    + " MERGE (sender)-[r:SendTo{uniqueReferenceTran:(line[2] + line[8])}]->(receiver)"
                    + " ON CREATE SET r.tranHashString=line[2],r.time=line[3],r.value_bitcoin=line[4],"
                    + "r.value_dollar=line[5],r.type=line[6],r.estChanAddr=line[7],r.outputIndex=line[8]");
        }else{
            System.out.println("withoutOutputIndex");
            sR = session.run(queryTran 
                    + " MATCH (senderAddress:Address {AddId:line[0]}), (senderAddress)-[:BelongTo]->(sender:Wallet),"
                    + " (receiverAddress:Address {AddId:line[1]}), (receiverAddress)-[:BelongTo]->(receiver:Wallet)"
                    + " MERGE (sender)-[r:SendTo{uniqueReferenceTran:(line[2] + 'default')}]->(receiver)"
                    + " ON CREATE SET r.tranHashString=line[2],r.time=line[3],r.value_bitcoin=line[4],"
                    + " r.value_dollar=line[5],r.type=line[6],r.estChanAddr=line[7],r.outputIndex='default'");          
        }

        sR.list();
        System.out.println("Tran rel created");


        String queryAddrDiffWallet = "MATCH  (a:Address)-[:BelongTo]->(w1:Wallet), (a)-[r0:BelongTo]->(w2:Wallet)" 
                + " WHERE w1 <> w2" 
                + " RETURN count(a)";
        sR = session.run(queryAddrDiffWallet);

        List<Record> records = sR.list();


        System.out.println(records.get(0).get("count(a)").asInt());
        System.out.println(records.get(0).get("count(a)").asInt() == 0);
        if(records.get(0).get("count(a)").asInt() != 0){
            sR = session.run("MATCH  (a:Address)-[:BelongTo]->(w1:Wallet), (a)-[r0:BelongTo]->(w2:Wallet)"
                    + " WHERE w1 <> w2" 
                    + " RETURN a");


        }

        String queryMergeWallet = "MATCH  (a:Address)-[:BelongTo]->(w1:Wallet)"
                + " WITH DISTINCT a, min(ID(w1)) as minId" 
                + " MATCH (minW:Wallet)"
                + " WHERE ID(minW) = minId"
                + " SET a.primWallAddr = minW.primWallAddr"
                + " WITH DISTINCT minW, a"
                + " MATCH (a)-[r0:BelongTo]->(w2:Wallet)"
                + " WHERE minW <> w2"

                + " WITH DISTINCT minW, w2, r0"
                + " SET minW.first_seen = CASE WHEN apoc.date.parse(minW.first_seen, 's',\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss\") < apoc.date.parse(w2.first_seen, 's',\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss\") THEN minW.first_seen ELSE w2.first_seen END,"
                + " minW.last_seen = CASE WHEN apoc.date.parse(minW.last_seen, 's',\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss\") > apoc.date.parse(w2.last_seen, 's',\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss\") THEN minW.last_seen ELSE w2.last_seen END"
                + " WITH DISTINCT minW, w2, r0"
                + " DELETE r0"
                + " WITH DISTINCT minW, w2"
                + " MATCH (b:Address)-[r:BelongTo]->(w2)"
                + " WITH DISTINCT r, minW, w2, b"  
                + " DELETE r"       
                + " WITH DISTINCT b, minW, w2"
                + " MERGE (b)-[be:BelongTo{uniqueReferenceBelongTo:(b.AddId + minW.primWallAddr)}]->(minW)"
                + " ON CREATE SET be.primWallAddr = minW.primWallAddr"

                + " WITH DISTINCT w2, minW"
                + " MATCH (w3:Wallet)-[r2:SendTo]->(w2)"

                + " MERGE (w3)-[rN:SendTo{uniqueReferenceTran:r2.uniqueReferenceTran}]->(minW)"
                + " ON CREATE SET rN.tranHashString=r2.tranHashString,rN.time=r2.time,"
                + "rN.value_bitcoin=r2.value_bitcoin,rN.value_dollar=r2.value_dollar,"
                + "rN.type=r2.type,rN.estChanAddr=r2.estChanAddr,rN.outputIndex=r2.outputIndex"

                + " WITH DISTINCT w2, minW, r2"
                + " DELETE r2"
                + " WITH DISTINCT w2, minW"
                + " MATCH (w2)-[r1:SendTo]->(w4:Wallet)"
                + " MERGE (minW)-[rN2:SendTo{uniqueReferenceTran:r1.uniqueReferenceTran}]->(w4)"
                + " ON CREATE SET rN2.tranHashString=r1.tranHashString,rN2.time=r1.time,"
                + "rN2.value_bitcoin=r1.value_bitcoin,rN2.value_dollar=r1.value_dollar,"
                + "rN2.type=r1.type,rN2.estChanAddr=r1.estChanAddr,rN2.outputIndex=r1.outputIndex"
                + " WITH DISTINCT r1"
                + " DELETE r1"
                ;
        if(records.get(0).get("count(a)").asInt() != 0){
        //merge any wallet containing same addresses and adjust the transaction as well (w2 merge to w1)
            try{
                sR = session.run(queryMergeWallet);                 
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                sR = session.run(queryMergeWallet);                     
            }
        }
        System.out.println("same wallet merged");



        System.out.println("----------abc----------------------" + num);





        //delete all wallets with no addresses  
        sR = session.run(
                " MATCH (n:Wallet)"
                + " WHERE NOT ()-[:BelongTo]->(n)"
                + " DETACH DELETE n"
        );
        System.out.println("Wall with no addr deleted");


    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver( "bolt://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.basic( "neo4j", "neo7474" ) );
        try(Session session = driver.session()){
            String mainDir = "C:\\Program Files\\neo4j-enterprise-3.1.1\\import\\csvsToImport\\csvs";
            // create index
            session.run( "CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (addr:Address) ASSERT addr.AddId IS UNIQUE");

            session.run( "CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (wa:Wallet) ASSERT wa.primWallAddr IS UNIQUE"); 


            System.out.println("aaa");
            int counter = 537;
            while(counter < 660){
                File dir = new File(mainDir + counter);

                if(dir.exists()){
                    System.out.println("aaa");
                    ImporterImprovedVersion a = new ImporterImprovedVersion(counter, counter > 260, session, mainDir);              
                }
                counter ++;

            }       
        }
    }
}
```

I imported many rows for nodes and relationships. By the time the exception is thrown, the graph has 184448 relationships, 82179 of them have 8 properties; and 117314 nodes, 69714 of them have 6 properties. I will update my question with this information. (Could the number of nodes and relationships along with their properties be the reason?)

Comment: You could possibly have a memory leak somewhere in your program, it would be better to show us the code.

Comment: which version of the driver do you use?

Comment: how much data is returned here:         sR = session.run(queryAddrDiffWallet);
List<Record> records = sR.list();

Comment: if you're only interested in the first record you should just get the first record and otherwise call sR.consume() for the rest

Comment: Also is there anything missing from the stracktrace? b/c it shows only infrastructure code.

Comment: you should also consume all your session.run() operations to empty the buffers / clean up resources

Comment: and how much data do you import how many rows for nodes and relationships and how many columns

Comment: @MichaelHunger Sorry for being late. Thank you for your hint about sR.consume(). I imported many rows for nodes and relationships. By the time the exception is thrown, the graph has 184448 relationships, 82179 of them have 8 properties; and 117314 nodes, 69714 of them have 6 properties. I will update my question with this information. (Could the number of nodes and relationships along with their properties be the reason?)

Comment: The driver I used is of the version 1.2.1.

Comment: @MichaelHunger  By "consume all your session.run() operations", do you mean that I should call this `sR.consume()` after this `sR = session.run(..);` ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to increase the heap size in the JVM (-Xmx option)? The CSVs you are trying to import may be too big.

Comment: It is true. See the new edit. Would the (-Xmx option) solve it? If yes, is there some other implication as the result of such altering?

Comment: If there is simply not enough memory for loading the CSV files it will solve it and it won't have any implications. If there is a memory leak, it will simply postpone the OOM error.

Answer (score 1):

`LOAD CSV` has built in batching possibilities. So whenever you are running out of memory using `LOAD CSV` use `PERIODIC COMMIT`. Read more in [documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-importing-large-amounts-of-data).

Example:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///customers.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Customer {companyName: row.CompanyName})
```

Comment: Actually each csv files I import are not very big, but I import a lot of them.